Can a SvelteKit App be turned into a web component?
I'm quite new to Svelte/SvelteKit but have been using Vue for years. I decided to port one of my Vue projects over to Svelte that is a custom web component that is used on several sites running on different frameworks.
Being new to Svelte, I selected SvelteKit when scaffolding the project as I didn't think it would make a difference.
I've created the entire thing and it works great but noticed that all the online guides for converting a Svelte app to a web component are Svelte specific and not SvelteKit.
The app itself only contains one single +layout.svelte and +page.svelte file in the routes folder.
Can a SvelteKit app such as the one I've created be turned into a web component or will I have to port this over to vanilla Svelte?

The major features from sveltekit are pretty well conceptually constrained to things that require backend functionality, like SSR, routing, and progressive web forms.  That doesn't mean what you've developed with sveltekit can't be ported over, but you can't expect full functionality.  I would expect the rule to be anything outside of building it as an SPA and anything that requires backend interaction won't lend itself to the concept of a web component.  If you want to keep those aspects I'd consider looking at doing a microfrontend

Why do you need a web component? Is this supposed to be a component library to be used outside of Svelte projects?

Hi @brunnerh, the web component is essentially a widget that can be embedded on any website or platform and is used to facilitate Open Banking payments. I created this just over a year ago using Vue2 and it’s been working perfectly but I’m looking to create the same thing using Svelte. I’ve ported the project over to Vanilla Svelte now but all the guides I’ve read so far on creating web components differ quite a lot.

SvelteKit can either be used to build full applications or component libraries.
If you did not set it up in the component library mode, I would suggest doing so and moving the components over.
There are a few things you need to do/be aware of here:

The routes are not part of the component library; they can just be used to for documentation or testing of the components. The components should be placed in the lib directory and exported from (or at the very least imported in)  the index.js there. You may also have to adjust the exports of the package accordingly if you want components to be importable in other packages.
Since you currently have a layout and a page: If those belong together as the final web component, you have to instead make both of those regular components and import one into the other and use it there in place of the layout's <slot/>.
The svelte.config.js needs to be configured to output web components via:
compilerOptions: {
  customElement: true,
},

The components need to declare their tag names, e.g.
<svelte:options customElement="my-element" />


SvelteKit component libraries by default currently only preprocess the components, to get plain JS that can be used anywhere, you need an additional build step. See this answer for an example. Including the resulting UMD script in the page should add the logic for the matching custom elements in the HTML.

Also, note that you do not necessarily need web components, to use Svelte components anywhere, if they are compiled down to plain JS. You can always instantiate and add them to the DOM via the client-side API.

So, I've ported my SvelteKit project to standard Svelte -  It was fairly quick and easy to do and as I'm not using routes, it makes sense. I'm however still stuck on how to compile this project down to plain JS.
I've created a new question for this as SvelteKit no longer applies and given more context of what I'm trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78260477/how-to-compile-a-svelte-app-to-a-web-component-vanilla-js-that-can-be-used-on-ex
Would appreciate any help.

I never said to not use SvelteKit, it's the intended way for building applications and component libraries. You are just making things more difficult for yourself.

I realise that and I still have both the SvelteKit & Svelte project available to me. I just thought if not using SSR, why add the extra overhead.

Consistency. Most people will use SvelteKit if they can, most answer will be for SvelteKit, as is this answer and the linked answer. You will have to know how SvelteKit works to transfer anything that is SvelteKit specific.
