How to compile a Svelte app to a Web Component/Vanilla JS that can be used on external sites?
About a year ago, I created a Vue web component that could be included on any website to facilitate Open Banking payments in the UK. We've even got a WordPress, Magento & Shopify plugins that uses this web component.
You can check out how it works here.
I've re-created the widget in Svelte and used Flowbite Svelte to style it.
I'm however stuck on how to export this out as web component or vanilla JS so that it could be used in exactly the same manner as the Vue version - A single JS file that contains all the functioning code, including Flowbite/CSS and the whole thing contained within a ShadowDOM.
I've seen conflicting guides online where compilerOptions: { customElement: true,} is either set in svelte.config.js, vite.config.js or rollup.config.js.
I was under the impression doing something like this in Svelte would be considerably easier compared to Vue, albeit this did massively help when doing it in Vue.
Someone kindly pointed me to this answer but I'm struggling getting it to work for the following reasons:

dist/index.js doesn't exist
When I run npm run build it generated 4 files in the
dist/assets folder: index-DwmGsLQW.js,
apexcharts.common.js & index-uK8bMt0h
Changed the entry point to index-DwmGsLQW.js and ran vite -c vite.js.config.js build which generated components.js, components.umd.js & apexcharts.common.js in the
the dist-js folder
Using this components.js on a plain HTML page is giving me the following error
in the console: Unexpected token 'export' (at app_2.js:113050:1)

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction of how to achieve what it is I'm after.
Project Structure

SvelteKit Version of Project Structure


(You don't need three backticks for inline code, just use one.)


dist/index.js doesn't exist

Because you are not using SveleKit, this is where it outputs the processed components/code (I even wrote as much in my answer: "This build operates on the output of SvelteKit which is written to dist and creates a separate JS output in dist-js"). Point the build directly to some index file in your source.

When I run npm run build it generated 4 files in the
dist/assets folder: index-DwmGsLQW.js,
apexcharts.common.js & index-uK8bMt0h

The hash in the file path will change every time some content changes, if anything add the package version instead.

Changed the entry point to index-DwmGsLQW.js and ran vite -c vite.js.config.js build which generated components.js, components.umd.js & apexcharts.common.js in the
the dist-js folder

You don't need a separate build at all (especially not one pointing to a file that will disappear at the slightest change) if you don't use SvelteKit/@sveltejs/package.
Set up one lib build that points directly to your source if you don't intend to publish the components for native usage in Svelte projects.

Using this components.js on a plain HTML page is giving me the following error
in the console: Unexpected token 'export' (at app_2.js:113050:1)

It's a module script, so either use the UMD version or set the correct type. (<script type="module" ...>).

Ok, so I've followed your guide for SvelteKit but there's still a few issues. I had to install ````@sveltejs/adapter-staticwhich is now building tobuildinstead ofdistwhich isn't really a problem. In thebuildfolder I've gotindex.htmlprobably due to me having'build/index.htmlas the entry point. The onlyindex.jsfile this SvelteKit project has is the default one in the lib``` folder which is empty. Have included an image of folder structure.

You have set it up wrong, it's building an application not a component library. You don't need the static adapter. Start with a new project via npm create svelte and make sure to select component library as template. The build script, packages and other things should look very different.

So that has solved the issue and it's nearly working now. I can see the component loading on a plain HTML page but there are a few issues. Tailwind isn't being included which means no styling and and images contained in the static/images folder aren't being included either. Lastly, I'm getting the following files generated: components.js, index-bNtX6Oh4.js & components.umd.cjs. I'm assuming it's the cjs file I should be using and is there a way to get only 1 single js file. Thank you for your help :)

Have created a new question for the Tailwind CSS issue as I believe that's the only remaining issue now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78263069/tailwind-css-missing-from-universal-svelte-web-component

There are specific instructions on the Tailwind site for how to integrate it into Svelte.

Also, stop creating new questions for everything, did you even search first?

I've literally been searching for hours but guides and docs are scarce on this topic. I've look at the Tailwind site but it still doesn't answer my question as why the CSS is missing after build as it works fine during development.
